# Auto-Fill Windows Security Credentials

Tags: authentication, windows-10, credentials

I am having a network issue that every time in a while it requires me to enter my windows credentials (it is company security thing)

If I don't do that I will have no internet connection on my laptop

The procedure I do every time the internet goes off

- I reset internet explorer settings
- Open a web page like stackoverflow in order to make the windows security popup show
  [image]

I have automated the above steps to be done using a batch file that I just double click

I need a way to enter the credentials of the windows security in order to finish my suffering

Anyone knows if there is a way to do it? and how?

Comment: Did you google for *windows macro recorder*? But you are trying to willingly bypass a company security rules, which can be seen as an internal security attack. You will have been warned...

Comment: @SergeBallesta no I didn't since I don't know about it I will now, the company rules don't forbid me from making a script to log in on my command, note that I don't want to record the credentials entered into the fields, I want to automate the filling of the fields where I will put my credentials to be filled automatically on the double click of a small script

Answer (score 0):

You are basically asking us to show you a way to bypass a "company security thing" and looking for a way to violate one of your company's security policies. If you tried to script your way around this issue, you'd probably have to store your credentials somewhere in plaintext(!) for a script to work with them. So my suggestion would be: don't do that.

If this procedure is really that bothersome to you and other users, talk to your IT Sec colleagues and explain your cause. This question is a good showcase on how excessive security requirements might lead to lessened security due to the bad UX and workarounds.